# gsutil AccessDenied Exception - Login Required in both API Explorer and Service Account

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am using gsutil with a service account to download a file from a gs bucket.  I ran it once an hour ago and it worked without a problem, and then I ran the same code again and I get an AccessDeniedException: 401 Login Required.

To get more information, I run the command with a -D flag, like:

```
gsutil -D cp gs://mybucket/file localpath
```

In the debug output, I look at:

```
Command being run: /path/to/gsutil
config_file_list: /path/to/boto/config
```

### Case 1: Running gsutil under a service account or as another user

I configured a service account using the executable at /path/to/gsutil, not gcloud auth or any other gsutil executable on the machine, using:

```
/path/to/gsutil config -e
```

This created a .boto config file in my home directory, $HOME/.boto, which I then moved to another location to refer to by the service.

Since I'm running the service as another user, I need to reference the newly-created .boto file.  I set the environment variable BOTO_CONFIG:

```
BOTO_CONFIG=/path/to/$HOME/.boto
export BOTO_CONFIG
```

I can confirm that I am referencing the correct config file by looking at the config_file_list variable in the gsutil -D command's output.

To set up the service account, I followed:

https://console.cloud.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts

The key file from the service account set-up process was downloaded, and the path to it is included during the gsutil config -e step.

However, the response to running the gsutil command from the service account is AccessDeniedException: 401 Login Required.

### Case 2: API Explorer

On further exploration, I used the web-based API explorer storage.objects.get at:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1/storage.objects.get

to get the object's "mediaLink".  When I click the mediaLink, I still receive a response that says "Login Required", despite being logged into my google account on the browser.

Why am I receiving the above "Login Required" responses in both cases, when I have set up the service account as instructed in Case 1, and am logged into the API explorer in Case 2?

Comment: Could you send the log of your gsutil -D command to gs-team@google.com?  As for the mediaLink (case 2), the browser login doesn't include OAuth2 credentials which would be needed to access that link.  If you want to access the object via the browser, you should use http://console.developers.google.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by looking at the read permissions on the .boto file.  The file that was created by

```
gsutil config -e
```

only had read permissions set for the current user.  Since it was being read by a service running as a different user, it wasn't able to read the file and yielding a 401 Login Required error.  I fixed it by adding read permissions for the service's group.

In the least sophisticated case, you could fix it by giving any user read permission with

```
chmod a+r .boto
```

Comment: For context: gsutil doesn't warn on a non-readable config file because Python's ConfigParser module silently ignores file read errors.  This is intentional so that you can specify multiple possible config file locations.